# Creating list of lists without duplication

Tags: python, list

I have a data structure with a lot of duplication. If I am to create a filtered list to list out all the unique types, I do

```
type_ids = []
for record in file:
    type_id = record['type_id']
    if type_id not in type_ids:
        type_ids.append(type_ids)
```

and I will get something like `type_ids=['A','B','G']`. Now I want something like a descriptive name fo the type along with the id, in a structure as `types = [ ['A','Alpha'], ['B','Beta'], ['G','Gamma'] ]` I tried

```
types = []
for record in file:
    type_id = record['type_id']
    type_name = record['type_name']
    if [type_id,type_name] not in types:
        types.append([type_id,type_name])
```

I get a list but with a lot of duplication and not all types represented. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: For the data you want to represent, I'd definitely recommend a dictionary.

Comment: I already have a dictionary from which I am extracting this data from. I need to feed these unique type ids and their names into a database table.

Comment: Realize there are no lists in `type_ids` if it has format `['A', 'B' 'G']`. Your `if` statement in the second block of code is asking whether there's a nested list `[type_id, type_name]` inside `type_ids` which will never be true, so your `if` block will always be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
types = set((r['type_id'], r['type_name']) for r in file)
```

Python has a `set` type builtin that is an unordered collection of elements. You can create a set of unique `(type_id, type_name)` tuples with this one line.

Comment: thanks. this is very quaint. I need this data structure to be mutable though, to append more data later. what would you suggest in that case?

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, your `if` statement will always be executed, which is probably resulting in a lot of repetition. `type_ids` is a list of strings; your if statement is checking for membership of a list. There are no lists of the form `[type_id, type_name]` in `type_ids`. I'm not sure if you're looking for membership in the already existing `type_ids` or membership in `types` list you're building.

Rather, you want something like this:

```
types = []
for record in file:
    type_id = record['type_id'] # Assuming these two lines get the data correctly
    type_name = record['type_name']
    if type_id not in type_ids: # e.g. if 'A' in ['A', 'B', 'C']
    # OR, if [type_id, type_name] not in types:
        types.append([type_id], [type_name])
```

But, I'd recommend storing your information in a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) format, which is specifically designed for associated key-value pairs:

```
types = {}
for record in file:
    type_id = record['type_id']
    type_name = record['type_name']
    if type_id not in type_ids:
    # OR, if type_id not in types:
        types[type_id] = type_name
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my question. It was a typing mistake while abstracting the question from the problem in my program. The duplication persists with that edit.

Comment: @yayu What is `file`?